# Couldn't find Category with 'id'=id

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-routes

When i click my link_to, it takes to http://localhost:3000/categories/id rather than http://localhost:3000/categories/1. When I put the 1 into the URL it then takes me to the correct page, but I want it to work through the link, and so i suspect it is a routing issue.

These are my routes

```
  resources :categories, only: [ :index, :show ] do
    resources :stocks, only: [ :index, :show ]
  end

  resources :stocks, only: [ :index, :show ] do
    resources :histories, only: [ :index ]
  end
```

My link to

```
<% @categories.each do |c| %>
  <%=  link_to category_path(:id) do %>
  <%= c.name %>
  <% end %>
```

And this is my categories controller

```
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @stocks = Stock.all
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    @categories = Category.where(id: @stocks)
    @stocks = Stock.where(category_id: @stock.id)
  end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to pass the id to the route, that's the variable part of it. change from

```
<%=  link_to category_path(:id) do %>
```

to

```
<%=  link_to category_path(c.id) do %>
```